# Behat selenium and angular ng-init

Tags: ajax, angularjs, symfony, selenium

I have symfony2 project with some angular.js on the frontend. I have also behat tests with selenium2 and have a problem when testing edit functionality. When page loads I have ng-init that calls a function which execute ajax call and populate input fields with values. All is good when I test manually but when I run behat tests the selenium browser does not execute ng-init and that ajax call that I need. Any experiences with selenium and angular ?

Comment: just call this function after declaring it in controller. Like `$scope.functionAjax();`

Comment: @Vineet the function works, what I need is to get it to work in my tests, I am using symfony2 with MinkContext so I cant call javascript functions directly

Comment: you can call this init function on `.run` function of angular js

Comment: @Vineet we are talking about php here. as I said angular.js part works just fine on the frontend

Comment: Oh. I'm sorry I got your question in wrong way.

Comment: No problem :) I hope that someone had the same problem